# Organisable list ( list who's items' order can be changed )

Tags: javascript, html

I was wondering if it is possible to have a list consisting of items that can be dragged and dropped higher or lower in the list; thus, changing the order of the list.

Would one do this with the HTML5 Drag and Drop API or something else?

I'd appreciate any help in achieving this or a basic version of this.

Comment: You mean like http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try jQuery UI . You can use it as is or edit the code to suit your needs.